# Libraries for writing imap mail _server_ in Java

Tags: java, imap

I've read this: http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html

I want to write an imap *server* rather than imap *client* in Java. What libraries should I be looking into?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this, when there are perfectly good existing solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you are asking for the libraries rather than the entire solutions, however I found these to be Java based servers:

1. [JAMES](http://james.apache.org/)
2. [Dwarf](http://www.gnome.sk/Dwarf/dwarf_mail.html)

As far as the libraries go you'll need libraries that can:

1. Parse IMAP requests
2. SSL handling
3. Authentication libraries [to verify the requesting user from your directory]
4. Caching frameworks to handle multiple requests to the same object

I would really not recommend writing a IMAP server from scratch unless that was your main business.

Comment: You did me one better. Thanks for pointing out the difficulties of writing an imap server -- truth be told; I just want one in Java; not to write one myself. JAMES/Dwarf looks nice.